# Twitter bootstrap with Laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am working on a laravel app, and I want to apply  a twitter bootstrap class "btn btn-primary" class.
 but It's doesn't apply any change on my button.

Firstly as in my mind I should run those two commands and I did that

> php artisan install
>
> php artisan dev

My button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location='{{ route('register') }}'">Button</button>
```

**Edit**

My .blade view

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>laravel app</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color:#24bee5;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            .panel-heading
            {
            font-weight:bold;   
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height ">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links" >
                    @auth

                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">home</a>

                    @else
                 <!--       <a href="{{ route('login') }}">login</a> -->

                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}" >Registration</a>

                    @endauth
                </div>
             @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md" style="font-weight:bold" >
                     Register
                </div>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location='{{ route('register') }}'">Button</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you link your css file??

Comment: no how to do that please

Comment: please add your full view file

Comment: Now  running  npm run development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add link on `<head></head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Webdev glad it helps :)

Comment: I apply those links in a new .blade view but bootstrap doesn't work!

Comment: it doesn't make any sense, it should work, may be try to copy full contents to the new one and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

You have to compile your syles and javascript with `npm run dev` and then link the compiled files in the blade file

Comment: how to link the compile files?

Comment: Install https://git-scm.com/downloads and run the command in the root folder of the website. To learn more about assets and compiling them have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix. It's a powerful feature of laravel that is worth to dig in deeper. It will save you a lot of time later on.

Comment: You can use the mix function like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">